# Import issues to github from end user

Tags: github, end-user

I have some end user web project and use github as bug tracker.

My end users is not programers and theys don't love github.

What are server or other possible things exists for bug importing to github from such end user?

Also need bugs exporting from github for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could enter their bug into a [bugzilla server](http://www.bugzilla.org/) that you would setup for your web users.

There exists some scripts like "[github issues export](https://github.com/mcepl/github-issues-export)" which export from GitHub issues back to said bugzilla server.

Comment: I find such service http://getsatisfaction.com/. Seems it is more user friendly but i don't know it github integration. I think that exists more other simular products.